# Angular Material Drag and Drop flexbox sizes lost on drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to add drag and drop capabilities to my list using Angular Material CDK Drag and Drop. However, when I drop an item, its flexbox alignment is lost and it displays differently.

[image]

The top item is after it has been dropped whilst the bottom is before.

[Stackblitz to demonstrate the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-punugt)

I have found a couple of issues that could be related:

- https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13288 - however, this appears to only be for preview of the item.
- https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13372 - however, this is for mixed orientation support (flexbox with wrap).

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the cdk drag drop updating the row's display style. Manually add `display: flex` to your css for class **cdk-drop-list** to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Z.Bagley. I had thought that the CDK wouldn't alter the display. I ended up adding the `display: flex` to `.cdk-drag` which worked nicely.